# Drawing a path from c# with relative coordinates

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics

Is there a c# equivalent of XAML lowercase commands used in Data attribute of Path ?

XAML:

```
<Path Stroke="Black" Data="M 100,200 c 100,25 400,350 400,175" />
```

From what I can see LineSegmenet, BezierSegment and other types of segments don't expose a property that would suggest a use of relative coordinates instead of default absolute.

Comment: The above geometry string creates a [StreamGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.streamgeometry.aspx). But [StreamGeometryContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms635540.aspx) also does not seem to have any methods that can deal with relative coordinates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
Path p=new Path();
p.Data = Geometry.Parse("M 100,200 c 100,25 400,350 400,175");
p.Stroke =new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
```